# 'Dropbox-iOS-SDK/DropboxSDK.h' file not found

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dropbox

I've been following this  [How to sideload apps on your iPhone using Xcode 7](http://bouk.co/blog/sideload-iphone/)

Downloaded the cocoapods, installed it, and of cause, ran the command `pod install`

It worked perfect so far. But, when i start the project `GBA4iOS.xcworkspace`
there is an error says

```
'Dropbox-iOS-SDK/DropboxSDK.h' file not found
```

[image]

It's weird, so I deleted the directory Pods, and re-pod install it.
I got a warning when it's done.

```
[!] CrashlyticsFramework has been deprecated in favor of Crashlytics
```

[image]

But I don't think it's the reason that cause that error.

Actually, I can find this head file in Pods

At the bottom of this screenshot is DropboxSDK.h

[image]

So, what's going on? How to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, and looking into the Pods/Headers/{Private|Public} folder in the Finder, I couldn't find the Dropbox-iOS-SDK folder.
So I created it `mkdir Dropbox-iOS-SDK`, and then link the headers from Pods/Dropbox-iOS-SDK with :

`ln -s ../../../Dropbox-iOS-SDK/dropbox-ios-sdk-1.3.13/DropboxSDK.framework/Headers/* .`

both in Public and Private.

I then had to disable Bitcode in Xcode under Build Settings/Build Options
and it worked !

Comment: after doing this, did you have any problems with DropBox syncing?

Comment: I haven't use it, so I can't tell.
But I can't assure you that my solution is the best one, just a workaround to get it work.

Comment: Copying these header files manually fixed the problem. I also had a 2nd, similar problem with the `CrashlyticsFramework`. I fixed it the same way like with `Dropbox-iOS-SDK`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `"${PROJECT_DIR}/Pods"` to `Header Search Paths` in **Build Settings**

Comment: This didn't do anything for me. But my problem is fixed with NaN's answer.